# Timer in UPdatePanel changes selectedIndex of RadioButtonList

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-ajax, updatepanel, radiobuttonlist

I have a situation where I have a page in ASP.NET. In this page I have a RadioButtonList, which contains 5 solutions to a question. The RadioButtonList is feeded by an object, which has these solutions.

I have a timer, which runs every second, to update loads of graphical controls. Everything works, BESIDES the RadioButtonList selection.

**This is what happends**:

When I select an item in the RadioButtonList and the timer tick, the selectedIndex of the RadioButtonLIst value is 0.

This means it selects the FIRST item in the list. However, IF I click an item, which has a "Yes" value in it (the value field can either have "No" or "Yes", it will stay at this item.

First of all, I have NO idea why the timer re-select my RadioButtonList selection, as any other Page_Load event does nothing. And even if that makes sense, I have no idea why it just re-selects SOME of the answers..

**I have the following HTML code:**

```
<asp:Timer ID="AssignmentTimer" runat="server" Interval="1000">
</asp:Timer>


<asp:UpdatePanel ID="FightUpdatePnl" runat="server" UpdateMode="Always" ChildrenAsTriggers="True">
   <Triggers>
      <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="AssignmentTimer" EventName="Tick"/>
   </Triggers>

   <ContentTemplate>
      <asp:Panel ID="AssignmentDiv" runat="server" CssClass="FightDiv">
      </asp:Panel>
   </ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

**I have the following code behind:**

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    SetupPage();
}

private void SetupPage()
{
   RadioButtonList list = new RadioButtonList();

   list.DataSource = question.PossibleSolution;
   list.DataTextField = "Content";
   list.DataValueField = "IsAnswer";
   list.DataBind();

   AssignmentDiv.Controls.Add(list);
}
```

**So, to summarize, my problem is...**

When the timer ticks, the RadioButtonList re-select item 0. This is however not consistent, and sometimes it doesn't re-select.
I'd rather it didn't re-select at all! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure if there are not other possible causes, but you should not bind your RadioButtonList in Page_Load on [postbacks](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.page.ispostback%28VS.71%29.aspx).
Otherwise the selection get lost.

```
if (!IsPostBack) {
   SetupPage();
}
```

Do that only when the page get first loaded and when you change its datasource(f.e in event-handler where you update the questions).

- You are adding the RadioButtonList dynamically to the page. Ok, this have to be done on every postback(in Page_Init if possible). But it don't need to be rebound to the datasource on every Postback, because the Viewstate will save the selection on Postbacks. So split the (re)creation and adding of the RadioButtonList from the RadioButtonList.DataBind. The first have to be done on every postback and the second only on first load and when the source has changed(f.e. in an event handler).
- Set the ID of the RadiobuttonList. Otherwise the ViewState will not be loaded after postback. The ID should be unique. If you are adding more than one RadioButtonList use a counter or such a thing.

Comment: True, but the problem with the UpdatePanel is it is updated all the time. This means that if we have an (!IsPostBack), the RadioButtonList won't be drawn at all! :-\

Comment: The RadioButtonList  would be drawn and retain its selection through ViewState but you wouldn't have the current database state for what you have the Timer.
You cant have both. Consider to update the datasource before you reload it.

Comment: I am sorry, but I don't really understand you mean.. Could you please explain a little further? :)
Thanks!!

Comment: You are adding the RadioButtonList dynamically to the page. Ok, this have to be done on every postback(in Page_Init if possible). But it don't need to be rebound to the datasource on every Postback, because the Viewstate will save the selection on Postbacks.
So split the (re)creation and adding of the RadioButtonList from the RadioButtonList.DataBind. The first have to be done on every postback and the second only on first load and when the source has changed(f.e. in an event handler).

Comment: Hi again. I just tried what you said. I moved the creation to OnInit, and made sure the DataBind() method only ran when needed. Using the debugger, I could see it only binds when page is loaded for the first time, and when source is changed....

But the problem is the same. The selectedIndex still goes to 0 and re-select items.. :-\

Comment: Set the ID of the RadiobuttonList. Otherwise the ViewState will not be loaded after postback(if i remember correctly).

Comment: I just tried setting the ID too, it changed nothing.. :-\ Do you have any other ideas?
I really appreciate your help, it means a lot! :)

Comment: I'm afraid that I'm at one's wits' end :-\

Comment: Thanks for the help by the way.. :) I used your ideas to a solution.. I just reacted on the selectedindex changed event and removed the button.. thanks again!